# Button IBaction Connection is showing unknown symbol and application getting exception unrecognised selectoe sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift4

I have IBAction for buttons Those buttons are used for InAppPurchase. Suddenly these connection are turned as symbols as shown in the screenshot and when I tap on it my app getting an exception. Can someone help me to solve this issue

> [*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Ascent_copy.SettingsTableViewController userPressedOnUnlockFullVersion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9e6b900000']
>
> [*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Ascent_copy.SettingsTableViewController userPressedRestore:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcc35033200']

[image: Image attached]

Answer (score 0):

I think, your IBAction connection is missing with that button. 
Remove actions of those buttons and connect again.

Answer (score 0):

Your two IBAction buttons :

- userPressedOnUnlockFullVersion
- userPressedRestore

Aren't correctly connected. So you must remove them by clicking on (x) And reconnect them. They must appear like the other IBAction buttons (black circle)

Answer (score 0):

Your two `IBActions` `userPressedOnUnlockFullVersion:` and `userPressedRestore:` are not available anymore. You might have renamed or deleted them.

Verify your IBActions then remove those action connections from the interface builder and try to reconnect to buttons. It might have new IBActions.